# c# Sockets use Ssl

Tags: c#, sockets, security, ssl

Is there a way to add SSL to my sockets? I just want to use my existing code, but all i found on the internet was for a different type of implementation.

```
    partial void btnConnectClicked(NSObject sender) {
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            lock (clientSocket) {
                clientSocket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 3333), new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), null);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    partial void btnSendClicked(NSObject sender) {
        try {
            string text = tbText.StringValue;

            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
            clientSocket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), null);

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult AR) {
        try {
            clientSocket.EndConnect(AR);
            SetEnabled();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR) {
        try {
            clientSocket.EndSend(AR);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

I hope anyone can help me

Comment: Use SslStream over Socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything I've read says to use [SslStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

[This guy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cgarcia/2009/08/21/enable-ssl-for-managed-socket-on-windows-mobile/) wrote a helper class around the Socket class for using SSL, but he admits in that post that SslStream would have made life easier.

Comment: This helped me a lot, Thanks

Comment: The link is broken now, unfortunately. Is the solution available somewhere else?

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser Not that I can find. But you're better off using `SslStream` anyway.